# How to add a multi select category and attribute filter on catalog page

Tags: magento2, catalog, filter, multiselect

My magento 2.3.3 theme provides me single select from same category or attribute.
[image]

Here if i select a sub category all the other categories will get disappears because it is single select.
But i want is a multi select filter where i can filter multiple sub categories and attributes.
Like this
[image]

Is there any free extension or we can do it by custom module.
Please Guide me.

Answer (score 0):

For that, I suggest you to Refer Welt Pixel free/paid extension.

https://www.weltpixel.com/improved-magento-2-layered-navigation-ajax-filter-multi-select-price-slider.html

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I have installed this extension but i dont know the reason its giving me excpected results ill try again with this

Comment: @SayyedHasan Check this one too https://www.magesolution.com/magento2-layered-navigation.html maybe it'll fulfill your need. It's also a free extension.

Comment: Ok ill check it

Comment: sorry to say but this extension does not provide anything . have a look at this https://prnt.sc/qrmkrg

Comment: Weltpixel extension is working as single select not multiple select

Comment: @SayyedHasan I have review Weltpixel extension demo and it's working on multi-select attribute. Check Climate attribute on demo.

Comment: Ok let me check can u share  screenshot please of output

Comment: @SayyedHasan Check the demo on your end. Use this link for your batter understanding. https://pearl.weltpixel.com/v7/apparel.html?climate=203%2C204&p=2

Comment: Probelm is weltpixel extension is working fine in plain magento but not working in my theme